# How Google Sheets ArrayFormula consider other column

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula

In Row 1 of [this sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1m-Y-T3WUv9wMmy_A5sYuppgSoeW1wcNGQkk2DYqbRH0/edit#gid=0) I have formulas like `=ArrayFormula(sum(if(and(not(ISBLANK(C$4:C$49)),$A$4:$A$49>=$A$1),1,0)))`.

[image: Google Sheets screenshot]

What am I doing wrong?

How can I change the formula such that the values in Row 1 from `C` to `F` show the counts of non-empty cells in the main part of the table but only when the Importance value of that row is `>=3`?

*P.S. If it's easier to demonstrate within an actual sheet, you can create a copy of my Google Sheet, edit your copy, change its permissions so that it's publicly-viewable and then share its URL here.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try either of the following (simpler) formulas

```
=COUNTIFS($A$4:$A$49,">="&$A$1,C4:C49,"<>")
```

OR (if you really want an array)

```
=SUM(INDEX(IF(($A$4:$A$49>=$A$1)*(C4:C49<>""),1)))
```

[image]

Functions used:

- [`INDEX`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242)
- [`COUNTIFS`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256550)
- [`IF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364)
- [`SUM`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093669)

Comment: Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Comment: Thank you!! Wow, this is so cool. And someone else also privately sent me 2 other solutions that work. It's so interesting how 4+ approaches work, and I hadn't been able to come up with even one of them.  `=ArrayFormula(MMULT(SEQUENCE(1,ROWS(A4:A),1,0),IF(C4:F<>"",1,0)*(A4:A>=A1)))` and `=SUM(FILTER(IF(C$4:C<>"",1,0),$A$4:$A>=$A$1))`

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to accept as well as sharing the alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following in C1 and drag it to F1:

```
=sumif($A4:$A,">="&A1,C4:C)
```

Or with a single formula in C1:

```
=index(query((A4:A>=A1)*(C4:F),"select sum(Col1), sum(Col2), sum(Col3), sum(Col4)"),2)
```

Comment: I appreciate your effort, but these don't work. The first one doesn't consider whether cells are empty. So its resulting values are wrong. And the second approach causes a #REF error as shown here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1m-Y-T3WUv9wMmy_A5sYuppgSoeW1wcNGQkk2DYqbRH0/edit#gid=1088211051

Comment: give edit access please.

Comment: If it's easiest to demonstrate within an actual sheet, you can create a copy of my Google Sheet, edit your copy, and change its permissions so that it's publicly-viewable, and then you can share its URL here. Thanks!